# Bulk insert failing: Explicit value must be specified

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have the following code to do a bulk insert into sql server ([taken from the example at the bottom of here](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3507171/Transferring-Data-from-One-Table-to-Another.htm)):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard ON

EXECUTE XP_CMDSHELL 'BCP AT100Reporting.dbo.Reported_Driver_ScoreCard out D:\temp\Reported_Driver_ScoreCard.txt -T -n'
BULK INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard 
FROM 'D:\temp\Reported_Driver_ScoreCard.txt'
WITH 
(
    DATAFILETYPE  = 'native',
    ERRORFILE = 'D:\temp\error.txt',
    MAXERRORS = 10000 
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard OFF
```

However, when I run this command, it will fail and give me this error message:

`Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'Reporting_DriverScoreCard' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.`

I think this is because there is an extra line on the end of the txt file being created so it is trying to insert a blank row when it gets to the end of the file (and all the other rows have an identity set for them.)

Is there any way to get this to work properly, as I have multiple massive dbs that I am trying to use this on?

Comment: Did you verify there *is* an extra line? Does the file provide identity values like the message tells you to do? How quickly does the BULK INSERT execute in seconds? Does it fail immediately or at the end?

Comment: It fails at the end, I have added the following values to the statements `-e` to the BCP and `KEEPIDENTITY` to the bulk insert but I can't verify the file as it is too large to open

Comment: Use a hex editor or copy just the first and last meg of the file to a new location. Or export less data using a view or queryout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out I needed the correct arguments adding to the query.  In the end, this is the query that has worked for me:

```
EXECUTE XP_CMDSHELL 'BCP AT100Reporting.dbo.Reported_Driver_ScoreCard out D:\temp\Reported_Driver_ScoreCard.dat -T -E -n -k'

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard ON

BULK INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard 
FROM 'D:\temp\Reported_Driver_ScoreCard.dat'
WITH 
(
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    BATCHSIZE = 5000,
    DATAFILETYPE  = 'native',
    ERRORFILE = 'D:\temp\error.txt',
    MAXERRORS = 10000,
    KEEPNULLS
);

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].Reporting_DriverScoreCard OFF
```